# Internet access to VMs via Vsphere ESXI 6

Tags: esxi

I installed Vsphere 6.0 on a VM workstation 11 and on booting it gave me an IP address (static) - 192.168.254.XX and i used the same address to log into the Vsphere Client.
In Vsphere Client, I created 01 VM. My ESXI machine in workstation is connected to physical NIC (Bridges connection) and is supposedly getting internet access.
How will the internet connection be routed to Vsphere VMs via ESXI system on VM Workstation. As per my understanding, the Vsphere client where my VMs are installed, is interfaced to ESXI system. So, do i need to NAT my NIC to the ESXI IP address or to my ISP address (DHCP)??

i want to give internet access to my VMs in Vsphere client How should i go about it? My internet connection is a DHCP based system.

Also, how to go about configuring DD-WRT to distribute internet to various VMs??

Answer (score 0):

your ESXI has a static ip correct was the static ip provided by the ISP? or is fake? if it fake NAT your way to ISP address or else do the ESXI ip adress

now for the DD-WRT there are **2 options**

**Simple Version**
Disable DHCP
Connect a LAN port to the main network / to the main Router's LAN port
Now you have an AccesPoint only setup, where clients are served IP details from your main network or main Router.

**Long Version**
Here's how to create a Wireless Access Point using dd-wrt v24. 
Hard reset or 30/30/30 the router to dd-wrt default settings
Connect to the router @ http://192.168.1.1

Note: If this router is wired to another router, there may be conflicts (both 
routers could have the same IP address). For the time being, disconnect this router from the main one.
Open the Setup -> Basic Setup tab

WAN Connection Type : Disabled

Local IP Address: 192.168.1.2 (i.e. different from primary router and out of primary router's DHCP pool)

Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0 (i.e. same as primary router)

DHCP Server: Disable (also uncheck DNSmasq options)

(Recommended) Gateway/Local DNS: IP address of primary router (many things will fail without this as your router will not be able to access the internet or 
another network without it)

(Optional) Assign WAN Port to Switch (visible only with WAN Connection Type set to disabled): Enable this if you want to use WAN port as a switch port
(Optional) NTP Client: Enable/Disable (if Enabled, specify Gateway/Local DNS above) Help

Save

Open the Setup -> Advanced Routing tab
(Optional) Change operating mode to: Router
Save
Open the Wireless -> Basic Settings tab
Wireless Network Name (SSID): YourNetworkNameHere
(Optional) Sensitivity Range: The max distance (in meters) to clients x2
Save
Open the Wireless -> Wireless Security tab
Note: Security is optional, but recommended! Clients must support whatever mode you select here.
(Recommended) Security Mode: WPA2

(Recommended) WPA Algorithm: AES

(Recommended) WPA Shared Key: >8 characters
Save
Open the Services -> Services tab

(Optional) DNSMasq: Disable (enable if you use additional DNSMasq settings)

(Optional) ttraff Daemon: Disable

Save

Open the Security -> Firewall tab

Uncheck all boxes except Filter Multicast
Save
Disable SPI firewall
Save
Open the Administration -> Management tab
(Recommended) Info Site Password Protection: Enable

(Recommended) Routing: Disabled (enable if you need to route between interfaces)

Apply Settings and connect Ethernet cable to main router via LAN-to-LAN uplink*

Reboot router to be sure all settings have been applied.

You may have to reboot your own PC or do "ipconfig /release" + "ipconfig /renew" from the Windows command line.